# How to compare database table with excel with same columns in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

I have one database table.And I have excel spreadsheet.The columns of these two tables are the same.I would like to compare the ID values ​​of these two tables and find them if they do not match the ID values ​​and save them to the database table.

**DATABASE NAME:** STUDENTSINFORMATION

**TABLE NAME AND COLUMN:** STUDENTS (ID,NAME,CLASS)

**EXCEL TABLE COLUMN:** (ID,NAME,CLASS)

I want to Students (ID) and Excel table (ID) column  I would like to compare the columns and insert these ids or ids into the students table if there are 1 different ids. How can I do this?

Comment: I want to try to this question and create two datatable but datatable did not fill.So  just wanted to specify that I use datatable. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you import your data from the Excel into a separate database table and then write the appropriate SQL to compare the two tables and then insert the difference into the final table. Which database are you using?

Comment: Hi I'm just using the sql database and I'm trading on this single database.
I don't know how to do it if I use another database.
The solution I'm dealing with is to read the database table if excel and compare it separately.
And find the difference and insert them into the database students table.I've been doing this for 3 days, but I couldn't do it that way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, not to create another database but to rather create another table within the same database. So currently you have the Students table, create another table call eg. Exceldata. Load load the data from the excel into that table. Then I am guessing you want to get those IDs that are in the excel but NOT in the table. To do that use the query below to know the difference and insert them into the Student table:
INSERT INTO STUDENTS (ID,Name,Class)
SELECT Exd.ID, Exd.Name, Exd.Class,
from Exceldata Exd
LEF JOIN STUDENTS Stu on Exd.Id = Stu.ID
WHERE Stu.Name IS NULL

Comment: So how do I delete this table again every time I insert it. Because my database tables are specific fixed tables.
Can I store datasets and compare datasets?
Because I don't know how to create another table after reading it and insert it into that table.
I'm sorry, I don't know, so I'm asking you these questions to be able to do it right.